Emma looks young for her age
(1) Emma looks young for her age.
[Case 1] Emma is 25 years old, but she looks 18 years old.
[Case 2] Emma is 58 years old, but she looks 45 years old.
I think that (1) is possible in Case 1, but I don't know whether it is in Case 2.
Is (1) possible in Case 2, although Emma is old?

Both are possible. The word 'young' in 'young for his/her age' is comparative, not absolute, and it would work if someone was 110 but looked 95. How anyone 'looks' an exact age after about 16 to 20 I don't know.

I am 72, but people think I am 60 to 65.

I know men of 50 that look older than me.

@MichaelHarvey, Indeed, I can tell by your posts that you look very young for your age!

@MichaelHarvey Thank you. Michael Harvey. I should have inserted "about" before "18/45". In Japanese, in Case 2, (1) is possible, but "Emma looks younger than she really is" sounds a little more natural to me, hence this thread.

Case 3: Emma is 18 (old enough to vote, drink, enlist, have sex, marry,,..) but she looks like a 14-year-old. She herself might say "It's a real bummer that I look young for my age. People keep trying to stop me doing what I want because they think I'm a child".

@FumbleFingers Did you downvote my question?

No, but I certainly thought about doing so.

@FumbleFingers Why?

I voted to close the question as "matter of opinion". I don't know what language you speak, but I expect looking older/younger than one's years is something that can be conceived and articulated in any language, and it's a matter of culture / local context which "incorrect direction" and which specific age-range might be commonly used and understood. You might as well ask what specific price range is likely to be involved in "It's expensive for what it is".

So, culturally there may well be different conventions about discussing an older or younger person's age. But regarding language usage, the example in the OP will be valid for any age.

@FumbleFingers My native language is Japanese. My question is about the usage of "young", not a matter of opinion. You seem to be assuming that what is obvious to you is obvious to every learner of English. Japanese has very little in common with English, so what is obvious to native speakers of English is very often by no means obvious to Japanese learners of English. By the way, please note that I am far from an advanced learner and that most Japanese have a much poorer command of English than French/German/Spanish/etc learners. Is this forum intended for advanced learners of English?

I'd guess that Japanese people are less likely than Anglophones to say someone looks younger (or older) than their age, for purely cultural reasons. For the same reasons they avoid referencing someone's bad breath or body odour. But this is culture, not language.

@FumbleFingers Japanse people very much like talking about someone's age and often say someone looks younger/older than their age. Your logic is totally incomprehensible to me. It is a shame that EnglishForums, which is very beginner-friendly, has stopped working.

We don't usually think, in absolute terms,  that someone of 50 is 'young', and that a woman of 35 is 'elderly', but we might say that someone of 50 is young to retire. When I was younger, a woman who was pregnant for the first time when aged 35 or older was called by doctors an elderly primagravida.

I always compliment someone who looks fitter, healthier i.e. younger than their biological age would suggest. The British and Europeans talk about how young (or old) someone looks ALL the time. Michael Harvey's initial comments confirm this. Think of all the women and men who do face lifts and botox, if it's not to appear younger then why do they undergo similar procedures?

"Young for her age" is a comparison.  Not an absolute.  Both Case 1 and Case 2 are correct.  However, in the case of 58 year old Emma, most people would phrase it differently such as "Emma does not look 58" or "I thought Emma was no more than 45".

"for her age" is a qualifier of the adjective "young".

Three dollars is expensive for a piece of chewing gum.
Forty dollars is inexpensive for a round-trip plane ticket.

The adjective expensive is relative, on a grade or continuum, and so is the adjective young in the assertion "looks young".

... 58 isn't so old ...
You can say Emma looks young for her age in either case.
"Young" is more a state of mind than a particular age.

The tag "young" was created in the original post. Please delete it from the site.

Why do you comment on my answer?  You could do a tag edit.

I can delete a tag from the post. But how can I delete a tag from the site?

By removing it from all posts.  But also be chill about it. A pointless tag is not that big of a deal. Mods may be able to block a tag to prevent it from being re-used, but that is for abuse or hate, it's not worth worrying too much about.
